# Formalize "Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo"

Tags: logic

<sub>Source: p 145. [*Sweet Reason: A Field Guide to Modern Logic*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1444337157) (2010 2 ed) by Henle, Garfield, Tymoczko.</sub>

> "Buffalo" sentences (pp. 73, 101, and 139) 
>   can be formalized if we establish two conventions. First, that the noun "buffalo" 
>   should be interpreted as "all buffalo" (or 
>   "all bison"). Second, if there is no object 
>   to the verb "buffalo", then we interpret it 
>   as "buffalo some buffalo" (or "intimidate 
>   some bison"). So "Buffalo buffalo" is "All 
>   bison intimidate some bison". Let Bx mean 
>   that x is a buffalo (or bison). Let Ixy mean 
>   that x buffalos (or intimidates) y. Then we can express "Buffalo buffalo" as ∀x ( Bx ⟹  ∃y(By ∧  Ixy) ).
>
> 17. Formalize "Buffalo buffalo buffalo 
>       buffalo buffalo" where we mean "All 
>       bison intimidate all bison, that all 
>       bison intimidate".
>
> [ p 360 : ] 17. ∀x ( Bx ⟹ ∀y ( ( By ∧  ∀z (Bz ⟹ Izx) ) ⟹ Ixy) )

The following was my attempt; I added colour and changed the brackets to ease reading.

[image]

Why should the red y instead be x (per the above answer)? I wrote the red y because the green restrictive relative clause modifies bison<sub>2</sub>, and not bison<sub>1</sub>.

Comment: You are right, this is an error, the original referent (x) is the subject and the pronoun refers back to the direct object (y) of the first verb, so in no place is the subject (x) the direct object of the verb.  In any good reformulation, there would never be and I whose second argument was x.

Comment: That said, this is still poorly constructed.  Where does the existential quantifier from the stated interpretation of "Buffalo buffalo" go when we start conflating sets?  "Children eat food mothers prepare" means "For child c, for food f if c eats f there exists mother m who preprepares food f".  Where is this final existential in the case in question?

Comment: intimidate has two senses, one transitive and the other deponent.  If people severely intimidate you in the transitive sense, that is mass oppression.  If people severely intimidate you in the deponent sense, you have a social anxiety disorder.  The book's answer only makes useful sense by conflating the two incompatible meanings onto a single predicate.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question is off-topic, being about semantics. It belongs on [the linguistics SE](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Translations in and out of logical formalism do traditionally belong here, rather than in math or language SE's, even if the difficulties are caused by mathematical or language problems rather than logical ones.  (How often do we discuss misinterpretations of Godel, Quantum Theory, or Latin terms in Augustine?)

Comment: The sentence has many meanings, thus many formalizations. Sources of differences in meaning: "buffalo" can mean either the city, bison, or intimidate (either as a transitive or intransitive verb in the indicative, or as an imperative). Thus, "buffalo buffalo" can mean either "bison from the city of Buffalo," "intimidate bison!", "bison (do) intimidate".  Each has a different formalization.

Comment: @jobermark +1. Thank you for your 1st comment that I understand. Sorry, but I do not understand [your 2nd](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/37076/formalize-buffalo-buffalo-buffalo-buffalo-buffalo#comment89025_37076). What exactly is poorly constructed? In your second sentence, I see only one existential quantifier : `there exists` for mother *m*.

Comment: Yes, there is only one, it is just the last quantifier.  But the example is a parallel construction to their interpretation, and their interpretation has no existential quantifiers at all, and no negations that would explain the transformation of the existing quantifier into a universal one.  When parallelism fails, it is a sign to look for either a reason or a flaw.  The example is a bad example.